# Разделить визуально строку

Tags: c++, строки

Подскажите пожалуйста возможно ли сделать вот так:

```
std::string my_string;

my_string = "Hello World Hell";
my_string = "Hello
             World 
             Hell";
```

То есть инициализировать строку - как бы визуально разделив ее на строки ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так устроит?

```
my_string = "Hello "
            "World "
            "Hell";
```

Comment: Спасибо. Так просто оказалось :)